# AFNetworking 3.0 The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

There are other questions with similar titles but none of them helped me. I've to send a `PUT` request to server in order to change the status of appointment so I've made this method `-(void)appointmentStatusChangedTo:(NSString *)statusID atAppointmentID:(NSString *)appointmentID` In which I'm setting the URL and Parameters as

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/API/Appointments/3",BaseURLString];
    NSDictionary *para = @{
                           @"AppointmentStatusId":statusID,
                           @"ID":appointmentID
                           };
```

Then I've made URL request as

```
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:string parameters:para error:nil];
```

After that I'm setting the header for an authorization token as

```
 NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userToken"]];

    [req setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

So finally I'm calling it as

```
[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error){
        if (!error) {
            if (response) {
                NSLog(@"Respose Object: %@",responseObject);
                [self.patientsAppointmentsTableView reloadData];
            }
        }
        else {
    // NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
        }] resume];
```

Now it is successfully sending the data to the server but as a response I'm getting

> Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct
>   format.

I am not sure what the response might look like at the moment as I'm not in contact with backend guy. But as far as I remember it was just a simple 1. SO kindly tell me how to handle any type of response using AFNetworking 3.0 or any change in my code.

Comment: What's your AFResponseSerializer?

Comment: @Larme what's the alternative? and yes the response is not JSON What should I put there.

Comment: Can you show me your response ?

Comment: I missread AFResponse and AFRequest.  Set the manager.responseSerializer to [AFResponseSerializer serializer] or something similar.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya there is no response. It is getting into error and error is mentioned in the question. Read my reply to Larme's comment. This is what I might be looking for.

Comment: @Larme I did `manager.responseSerializer = [AFResponseSerializer serializer];` and it is giving me an in line error that `Use of Undeclared identifier AFResponseSerializer`

Comment: however by doing `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];` give me response

Comment: Sorry, I coded from memory, didn't remember exactly the name of classes. Does it work now beside compiling ?

Comment: @Larme yes it worked with `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`

Comment: That's weird. If you use `AFJSONResponseSerializer` instead, it doesn't work? If no, the issue is from the back end that seems to do weird things.

Comment: @TalhaCh Kindly response of answer.

Comment: @EktaMakadiya if you know magical record and core data kindly have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956814/how-to-fetch-and-display-objects-in-relationship-using-magical-record

Comment: @TalhaCh Yes sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use below code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setStringEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

manager.requestSerializer=serializer;
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code using Afnetworking 3.0

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        self.responseHandlers(YES,responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        self.responseHandlers(NO,nil);
    }];
```

Comment: How do you put "Bearer AccessToken" in your code like the OP is doing?